# Neo4j cypher Query - How to get specific labels data?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1

I want to get only customer and supplier name and ID using cypher query.

```
"Match (n: customer:supplier) where has (n.ID) return n.ID,n.nme";
```

How to combine 2 labels to get the data?

Above query is getting syntax error. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This for OR label matching:

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE (n:customer OR n:supplier) AND exists(n.ID)
RETURN n.ID, n.nme
```

This for AND label matching:

```
MATCH (n:customer:supplier) 
WHERE exists(n.ID)
RETURN n.ID, n.nme
```

Comment: Thanks. AND label matching is return nothing. But we have data in both labels. I'm using neo4j 3.4.6

Comment: The AND label matching means a node that has both the `customer` and `supplier` labels. Are you sure you have a node with both? Is this the correct case for the labels (Customer/Supplier maybe)?

Comment: I'm getting records when running (n.customer) only but with AND return nothing.

Comment: What does this return? `MATCH (n:customer:supplier) RETURN n`

Comment: It says "(no changes, no records)"

Comment: So you have no nodes with both these labels.

Comment: "MATCH (n:customer) return n " another query " MATCH (n:supplier) return n" return 100's of records

Comment: Yes. That means there are nodes with the label `customer` and there are nodes with the label `supplier`. But that doesn't mean that there is a node that has both these labels. You need the OR label matching.

Answer (score 0):

The `has()` function has long since been deprecated and removed. Use `exists()` instead.

Also I'm not sure what you mean by `combine 2 labels to get the data.` The query as it is now will only match to nodes with both the :customer and :supplier label. Is that what you want?